# "Warning. Error encountered while saving cache ... can't dump anonymous class" Update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, susy

Has anyone been able to squelch these warnings, while the sprockets-rails/sass-rails folks iron out the issue? I'm dealing with super-slow compiling times in development. I know that they're not actually harmful, but they're driving me nuts.

I'm using Rails (4.1.6), the 5.0Beta of sass-rails, and the newest sprockets-rails (2.2.0) gem that works with my setup (3.0Beta doesn't work yet).

I know I can downgrade to Sass 3.2 but I have sprinkled Susy 2 all over my site and want to keep it that way if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: @OhHendrie If it's a duplicate, why did you answer it anyway?

Comment: Because @Macnab was looking for an answer. Why'd you downvote it if it was a valid answer?